# What is a community copy?

Tags: terminology, publishing, indie-rpg

On my question [Where did the concept of community copies originate in the indie scene?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/193026/where-did-the-concept-of-community-copies-originate-in-the-indie-scene) an up-voted comment asked the question: What is a community copy?

So what is a community copy in the indie ttrpg space?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### "A limited pool of freely available copies that anyone could claim."

Dee Pennyway explains community copies on [their blog](https://mnemonicrpg.com/blog/game-design/communitycopies/) (emphasis mine):

> It used to be that if you had a price on your game, you also had a note in your store that said people could email you or message you on Twitter to ask for a free copy.
>
> What I heard from people who did this was that it was fine for a bit, but eventually the load of fielding requests for free content became a source of stress.
>
> Matthew Balousek wrote a quick explanation of his solution: to use itch’s Rewards system to supply **a limited pool of freely available copies that anyone could claim.** No emails, no messages, just a field in the dashboard that could be updated manually when the pool ran out.

Dee notes in that blog article that they are not the inventor of the idea:

> First, a disclaimer: I did not “invent” Community Copies. It was a feature that already existed in itch.io’s system, Matthew Balousek wrote a quick explanation about them, and then I gave the idea a “name” and wrote a longer, more in-depth tutorial for setting them up.

Andrew Berdan gives a tutorial on setting up community copies on itch.io in their article [Community Accessibility on itch.io](http://berdan.ca/andy/community-accessibility-on-itchio), and mentions at the end of the article:

> One last thing, giving thanks to Dee Pennyway and Matthew R.F. Balousek. This concept is not wholly my own, and it came out of collaborative discussions between the three of us. Make sure to check out their itch pages too!

Answer (score -4):

> **community copy** *noun*
>
> A free copy of a product provided to parties interested in the themes of the product, with the hope of positive reviews to assist a product in reaching a larger market. Strongly associated with vendor itch.io.
>
> See [review copy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/review-copy) for a related term, without the self-selection of recipients or trappings of good will.

Comment: This reads like it was taken from somewhere else.  If so, that source should be cited.

Comment: @jwodder Nah, just me being cynical in the style of a dictionary.